# JSTL date comparison/finding date difference

Tags: date, compare, jstl

I have a problem where I want to compare two dates or in other words I want to find the difference of two dates in JSP using JSTL.

I have seen many solutions like creating a JSP:bean of Date object. Other ones were more messy solutions.

Can anybody please provide me a cleaner solution so that I can do this with JSTL only? I need a solution somewhat like SQL DATEDIFF function in JSTL

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) to extract the year from it so that you can do the math on it.

**Edit :** Ihen use two varibles to store both dates

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date1}" pattern="yyyy" var="Date1" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${date2}" pattern="yyyy" var="Date2" />

<c:if test="${Date1 le Date2}">
    <doSomeLogic/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks Monicka for replying, but the problem is that I dont have any constant date like 1970 in your example. It will be dynamic so I need to find the difference between two dates.